# Rabbi Feinstein's commentary on end of parsha's simanim and numbers

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, midrash, simanim

In this [Hanukah / Miketz](https://www.dailyhalacha.com/Derasha/29.pdf) drash, Rabbi Mansour mentions a Rabbi David Feinstein sefer (book) on some parshiot simanim and numbers. Specific to the reference in the drash, which book is he referring to and is there an English version?

Comment: His book is called seasonings of the Torah. It's in English. The standard artscroll English chumash has an explanation from Rabbi Feinstein at the end of each parsha concerning the mnemonic for the number of psukim in the parsha.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for R Feinstein's book, or any book on this subject? Please [edit] to clarify as it is now unclear to me.

Comment: http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578190607.html

Answer (score 2):

It’s called **[Seasonings of the Torah:](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578190607.html)**
*Fascinating Parashah allusions based on letters, vowels, numbers and history*

Here is the book’s summary from ArtScroll.com

> Enter the world of deep Torah insights through the eyes of Hagaon Harav David Feinstein. The Rosh Yeshiva of Mesivtha Tifereth Jerusalem, Rabbi Feinstein is one of the most distinguished halachic authorities in this generation. Less known, but of significant grandeur, are his weekly lectures on the parashah that keep scholars and laymen riveted to his words. The Rosh Yeshiva's parashah teachings are enlivened by brilliant conceptions in gematria that go far beyond simple allusions contained in the numerical values of words. Rabbi Feinstein's unique approach elaborates on gematria in the broadest sense: ingenius rearrangements of letters and vowels render meanings never before revealed.
>   The many people who attend Rabbi Feinstein's parashah talks come away with inspiration that lasts all week long. Now you too can share these gems. Committed to the printed page, his insights are there for the asking - to enrich your Shabbos table, to inspire your family and to help you transcend the everyday tasks of life.

Comment: I hope he does a better job than the way he's represented in the Stone Chumash.  The things they say in his name there are not at all developed and often don't make sense.